# Adding a CF site on IIS on AWS EC2

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, coldfusion-11

I just started using EC2 on AWS and I am trying to add a new coldfusion site to IIS but for whatever reason is not working. I added a new site as I did it hundreds of times on my previous setup and then I am trying to call the site from my browser but it's timing out. Is there anything special that I have to do that it is specific to EC2's setup. I used an AMI of CF 11 and windows server 2012 for my setup on an m3.large instance.

The CF administrator is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing I had to do is add the new site to the `hosts` file and it work.